# covariance between sum and elements of sum, given the weighting of the elements, their variances and the covariance between elements

Tags: variance, covariance, sum

For simplicity let's say that M consists out of two elements: A and B.

The weighting of A is w(A) and of B it is w(B). Hence w(A)+w(B)=1.

Both weightings are given. Also given is Var(A), Var(B) and Cov(A,B).

What is Cov(A,M) and Cov(B,M)?